# Obfuscating C++ function calls with standard template programming

Tags: c++, templates, obfuscation, disassembly

I saw the `ADVobfuscator` project which has a [finite state machine obfuscation](https://github.com/andrivet/ADVobfuscator/blob/master/Lib/ObfuscatedCall.h) for function calls. However, this functionality requires `Boost` which I cannot use for a certain project. Is there a standard `C++` way of writing templates to obfuscate arbritrary function calls in a similar fashion as this library? Or maybe any hints towards accomplishing this?

```
function_to_protect("did", "again");
OBFUSCATED_CALL(function_to_protect, "did", "again");
```

The goal is that calls/references to the protected function/library do not show up in disassemblers like `IDA Pro` or `Ghidra`.

See [these](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-14/materials/eu-14-Andrivet-C-plus-plus11-Metaprogramming-Applied-To-software-Obfuscation.pdf) slides for illustration.

I do not want to define `struct`s or function wrappers similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33512319/3764804) answer since it's far less elegant than wrapping calls into a `macro`. Plus, the references to the functions still show up at initialization.

Comment: You might write your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) doing obfuscation. You may need to ask your lawyer about the legality of doing so

Comment: There is no standard way. What's wrong with the solution in the linked slides?

Comment: @rustyx: Unfortunately I cannot use `Boost` on the platform I'm targetting so the solution in the slides cannot be used.